# Xamarin Studio: Add UIimageView to UIView

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I want to add a imageview to my view, but the image doesn't appear.
Whats wrong with my code? Thank you for Help.

```
 ...Constructor(UIImage _pickedImage......

UIImageView iv = new UIImageView (this.Bounds);
iv.Image = this.pickedImage;
this.AddSubview (iv);
iv.Release ();
```

Answer (score 1):

You code snippet is rather short but you should **not** call `iv.Release ();` since you'll unbalance the reference counting of the native (ObjC) `UIImageView` instance.

In fact you *almost* never have to call this method yourself since Xamarin.iOS has a garbage collector (GC) that will, when disposing the object, automatically call the `release` selector (just like a `retain` will be done when creating the managed instance).

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem today, and found that this question had no proper answer yet on how to solve it. So for the sake of future references, I will explain how I solved it.

I loop through a list that contain images, depicted as `item`.
First, create the UIImageView

```
UIImageView imageView = new UIImageView();
```

Then I take the byte-array of the image, and convert it to an UIImage

```
UIImage image = Utilities.ToImage(item.ImageBytesArray);
```

Then, set the UIImageView with the UIImage

```
imageView.Image = image;
```

Next up is what solved the main issue for me, not showing up. So, we're going to get the screensize and store it in `screen`

```
var screen = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
```

Set the frame of the UIImageView. This creates the UIImageView that can be seen. My offset from the top had to be 400 in order to not overlap other content.
`CGRect(xOffset, yOffset, width, height)`

```
imageView.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 400, screen.Size.Width, 300);
```

I use a scrollview, so I add it to that. Can also be `this`

```
scrollView.Add(imageView);
```

> UIImageView imageView = new UIImageView();
>       UIImage image = Utilities.ToImage(item.ImageBytesArray);
>       imageView.Image = image;
>       var screen = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
>       imageView.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 400, screen.Size.Width, 300);
>       scrollView.Add(imageView);